# Sudoku in AnuglarJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, sudoku

So, I have a sudoku generator, when accessing through API, it generates a Sudoku board (JSON array) which then with AngularJS and ng-repeat in a tabled I am displaying the Sudoku board on the page.

So far, this is what I have. What I want to achieve is to highlight all the elements that are within the box plus the row and the column. Now the row and the column is highlighted but how can I also highlight the elements that are marked with yellow in the picture below because those elements belong to the box:
[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body ng-app="Sudoku">
<!--    SUDOKU BOARD    -->
<div class="sudoku-game" ng-controller="SudokuController">
    <table class="sudoku-board" ng-init="getSudoku()">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="sudoku in sudokuGrid track by $index" ng-init="row = $index" class="sudoku-row" ng-class="{'highlight':rowSelected === row}">
                <td ng-repeat="number in sudoku track by $index" ng-init="col = $index" class="sudoku-col" ng-class="{'highlight':colSelected === col}">
                    <div class="sudoku-cell" ng-class="{'selected':isSelected === ((row*10) + col)}" ng-click="selectedCell(row, col)" ng-keyup="insertNum($event)" tabindex="1">
                        <span class="prevalued" ng-if="number !== null" ng-bind="number"></span>
                        <span class="emptycell" ng-if="number === null" ng-bind="emptyCell"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my code in JavaScript for the selectedCell(row, col) function

```
$scope.getCellPosition = function (row, col) {
    return (row * 10) + col;
}

$scope.selectedCell = function (row, col) {
    $scope.isSelected = $scope.getCellPosition(row, col);
    $scope.rowSelected = row;
    $scope.colSelected = col;
    console.log($scope.isSelected);
}
```

This is how I get the data for the Sudoku Board from API in JSON format:

```
[
  [
    9,
    2,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    3,
    8
  ],
  [
    5,
    4,
    3,
    9,
    null,
    null,
    7,
    null,
    null
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    3,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ],
  [
    1,
    7,
    null,
    null,
    3,
    9,
    4,
    5,
    null
  ],
  [
    8,
    3,
    5,
    null,
    1,
    null,
    null,
    9,
    null
  ],
  [
    null,
    9,
    2,
    5,
    7,
    6,
    null,
    1,
    3
  ],
  [
    null,
    1,
    8,
    null,
    null,
    5,
    null,
    2,
    null
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    6,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    7,
    null
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    4,
    2,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    8,
    null
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an highlight class to cell being in the square of the selected cell:

```
<div class="sudoku-cell" ng-class="{
  'selected':isSelected === ((row*10) + col),
  'highlight': isHighlight(row, col),
}" ng-click="selectedCell(row, col)" ng-keyup="insertNum($event)" tabindex="1">
```

In your js:

```
$scope.isHighlight = function (row, col) {
  // Add debugging functions
  //
  console.log({
    row,
    rowSelected: $scope.rowSelected,
    col,
    colSelected: $scope.colSelected,
  });
  // Return the boolean
  //
  return Math.floor(row / 3) === Math.floor($scope.rowSelected / 3) 
    && Math.floor(col / 3) === Math.floor($scope.colSelected / 3)
}
```

Comment: hmm.. I see the point here, however now every cell is highlighted: check on the following link [link](https://imgur.com/a/GlaQ3mJ)

Comment: @VictorGavrilovic look at this example https://jsbin.com/losotetuva/1/edit?console

Comment: Yup, understood - I was trying to do something similar to this, but still, I cannot get it working with the AngularJS.. Any ideas what to change in the HTML code?

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                if (Math.floor(i / 3) === Math.floor($scope.rowSelected / 3)
                    && Math.floor(j / 3) === Math.floor($scope.colSelected / 3)) {
                    console.log("I: J: ");
                    console.log((i*10)+j);
                } else {
                    console.log("Empty");
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: I added this inside my controller, and with the code above, in the HTML I only get the last one, this is what I have in my div: `<div class="sudoku-cell" ng-class="{'selected':isSelected === ((row*10) + col), 'highlight':isHighlight === ((row*10) + col)}" ng-click="selectedCell(row, col)" ng-keyup="insertNum($event)" tabindex="1">`

Comment: Is there any way to return all of the value so I can catch them somehow in HTML in the ng-class?

Comment: @VictorGavrilovic you can add a method in the Angular component, pass the current row and column and return true if the cell has to be highlighted. I update the answer.